# How setup valuegetter for auto Group Column in Ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have `autoGroupColumnDef` and I want to setup text filter. But values of the column come from `getDataPath` method. But I need another value in the filter.

```
autoGroupColumnDef: {
    headerName: "Systems",
    filter: 'text',
    valueGetter: function(params) {
        var result = params.data.hospName || params.data.hospitalSystem;
        return result;
    },
    cellRendererParams: {
        suppressCount: true,
        innerRenderer: function(params) {
            var result = params.data.hospName || params.data.hospitalSystem;
            return result;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Let's assume that you have custom filter which is not part of data, then on applying that text filter there would be no data right? OR am I missing the use case explained here?

Answer (score 0):

After trying on couple of things, 
Option 1: You can make use of `[filterParams][1]`. This only helps to play around with options/choices in the filterMenu..

```
function filterCellRenderer(params) {
    //other than params.value nothing else will be there..
    // params.data won't be there when its called from filter popup
    return params.value+" Custom";
}

var gridOptions= {
    ...,
    treeData: true,
    components: {
        ...,
        filterCellRenderer: filterCellRenderer
    },

    autoGroupColumnDef: {
        ...,
        filterParams: {
            cellRenderer: 'filterCellRenderer',
            //values: ["A", "XYZ"] //you can feed directly specific values. These need to be part of filePath. Else filtering won't work.
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2: If you are looking for custom filter (tweak with GUI), or you want to post processing after it has been configured by ag-grid you can define the following:

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    getMainMenuItems: getMainMenuItems,// function to build your own menu
    postProcessPopup: function(params){
          // edit the popup.. 
          //params.type gives whether its column menu or not.
          //params.ePopup gives handler to popup which you can modifiy.

    },
    ...
}
```

**OR** you can build your own custom filter as described [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/)